# What is the difference between vector error correction model and UVECM?

Tags: vector-autoregression

What is the difference between vector error correction model and UVECM? Which one is better to use for a 30 years time series data (to study long term and short term relationship) which has some missing values?

Comment: What is a UVECM? And is your data monthly, quarterly or yearly?

Comment: I meant unrestricted VAR and my data is annual. thanks

Comment: If your data is annual you have 30 data points. You can't do much meaningful statistics with such small sample.

Comment: thanks a lot. what other model do you suggest me please?